# When dealing with numbers in bash when is [[ ]] preferred over (( ))

Tags: bash

Just out of curiosity is there ever a reason to prefer something like:

```
while [[ $number -lt 10 ]]
```

over

```
while (( $number < 10 ))
```

They seem to do the same thing. I'm wondering if maybe there is a performance benefit with one of them or maybe some portability concerns with `[[ ]]`?

Comment: Short answer: When it's usable, `(( ))` is _always_ preferred over `[[ ]]`... but quite a lot of folks simply don't know it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither is standard, so portability is not an issue. If you are only performing simple comparisons, there is little difference betwee

```
if [[ $number -lt 10 ]]
```

and

```
if (( number < 10 ))
```

aside from the ability to drop the `$` from the second (since all strings are assumed to be variables and dereferenced) and readability.

You might prefer `[[...]]` when your conditional combines arithmetic and non-arithmetic tests:

```
if [[ $number -lt 10 && $file = *.txt ]]
```

vs

```
if (( number < 10 )) && [[ $file = *.txt ]]
```

You would probably prefer `(( ... ))` if your comparison involved some computations:

```
if (( number*2 < 10-delta ))
```

vs the needlessly complex

```
if [[ $(( number*2 )) -lt $(( 10-delta )) ]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago when you wanted to have any kind of comparisons you was using program "test", which was usually symlinked to name "[".

So you had expressions like:

```
if [ ..... ]; then
```

test by default compared asciibetically, and if you wanted numerical comparison, you had to use -lt/-gt and similar.

Then, bash got it's own internal test engine. To use it you use [[.

So the same syntax you had earlier:

```
if [ ... ]; then
```

could be rewritten as:

```
if [[ ... ]]; then
```

and do the same, with the exception that comparison was done in bash itself, and didn't require fork/exec of test program.

Since now it's not call to external program, it's simpler to add another way to compare numerically. Hence (( )) appeared.

It has certain benefits, but one that is commonly overlooked is that it imposes numerical *context*.

Which means that you can have something like:

```
i=1
(( i++ ))
echo $i # will return 2
```

Long story short - for comparisons, it doesn't matter *much*. but it pays to learn more about (( )) and [[ ]] in man bash.

Answer (score 0):

`((` and `))` allow you to use all complex arithmetic operators but `[[` and `]]` allow only restricted comparison defined in `man test`

I woud prefer using `((` and `))` as it also doesn't enforce all spacing restrictions. You can very well use:

```
while ((number<10))
```

OR

```
while ((number*2<10))
```

etc.

Comment: [[ is not the same as test.

Comment: @depesz: Agreed it is not but operators it allows are what used by test.

Comment: yes, but [[ ]] is not *limited* to test capabilities. It can do more.

Comment: @depesz: Yes it can but compared to `(( and ))` it is severely limited.

Comment: well, in the same sense `(( ))` is "severely limited" to determine if a file is a directory or a symlink: `(( ))` and `[[ ]]` serve different purposes with a small area of overlap.

Comment: @glennjackman: True and I wrote clearly `(( and )) allow you to use all complex arithmetic operators`. I was only referring to arithmetic operations.